# Erf() in VBA-Excel code doesn't work in Excel 2003

Tags: excel, add-in, vba

I need to calculate the error function, Erf(), in my VBA Excel program. I have implemented something like that:

```
aux_A = -Application.WorksheetFunction.Erf(p)
```

Previously, in Excel 2007, I install Analysis Toolpak Add-in and it works perfectly but, in Excel 2003 it doesn’t work (and the add-in is installed too).

**What’s the problem?**

*(Please, note that I want to use the result in the VBA code, not in the Excel sheet).*

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get a compile-time error? Do you get the wrong result?

Comment: are you sure that function is available in the Analysis Toolpack for Excel 2003 ?

Comment: is the Analysis Toolpack for Excel 2003 properly loaded by Excel?

Comment: Heinzi: the error is:  erro '438' in execution time, the object doesn't admit this property or method. Philip: yes, I checked it and the Analysis Toolpack is properly loaded in my Excel 2003 SP3. It seems that this function is not available in this Toolpack but, where is it? Is available in somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Before Excel 2007, Erf was in the Analysis Toolpack so you had to call the functions directly (Without the `WorksheetFunction` part)

```
aux_A = -Erf(p)
```

Begining with Excel 2007, they move many functions into the WorksheetFunction library and that is why you now have to use `WorksheetFunction.Erf(p)`.

In the VBA Editor, press F2 and search for Erf.  You will see that the library and Class is different in versions prior and post 2007.

Comment: Sorry, but getting aux_A=-Erf(p) it gives me a compilation error (in Excel 2003 Professional Edition SP3 and the ToolPack installed). More, if I put "Erf" in the VBA Editor it doesn't give me any result.

Comment: @juanjosanz  Do you have both, the "Analysis Tollpack" and the "Analysis Tollpack - VBA" installed and checked?

Comment: Yes CaBieberach, both of them are installed and checked, so I'm lost. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the Erf function take 2 parameters (upper limit, lower limit)?

Comment: Actually yes it CAN but doesnt HAVE to. The excel implimentation of Erf allows for integration from a lower limit other than zero as well as a uniparametric implimentation. ie  in excel Erf(2,3) is equivilent to (Erf(3)-Erf(2))

Answer (score 0):

1. Add "Analysis Toolpack - VBA" in Add-Ins (Tools -> Add-Ins)
2. Add reference to **atpvbaen.xla** in VBA project editor (Tools -> References)
3. Try:

   n = Erf(0.5)

Works for me.